# Python Check existing value row by row from the Data Frame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any ways to using pandas checking the existing value row by row ?

This how  my Data Frame looks like

**Data Frame**

```
Log ID       User ID       Name       Phone Number     
1            001           Jack       123456789
2            002           Jackie     123456780
3            003           Jacky      123456700
4            004           Ben        123456000
```

The data I want to check is (Jacky, 123456700) is it in the Data Frame or not.

If exist then I just ignore this data else insert into the Data Frame

Comment: Could you explain more? What do you mean by ignore and insert? Do you want to remove the data and then insert.

Comment: If that data exist then i don't insert into the Data Frame. No removing any things from the Data Frame.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Insert what where? It is already in your shown data frame.

Comment: That why I need to check is it the data is inside the Data Frame or not. If the data is not inside the Data Frame, then ONLY I insert into the Data Frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select and check with logical AND `&` for `Name` and `Phone Number` with [pandas.DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
>>> name, phno = ('Jacky', 123456700)
>>> ((df['Name'] == name) & (df['Phone Number'] == phno)).any()
True
```

if `True` then you can ignore and if not, you can insert into the `df`